# How can I retrieve workspace name, user, and password to login to an Apex app created by a deceased manager?

Tags: passwords, apex, workspace, names

My manager is dead and he was created apex app.
I need to know workspace name , user , password to login to app

(apex_version 20.2.0.00.20)

(Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0)

I need help for that please if many mothed it we'll be great.
Thanks

I didn't doing anything